# Getting year from a timestamp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset that contains a column that is a timestamp and I need to get the year from the timestamp. The dataset looks like this:

| rideable_type | started_at | ended_at | member_casual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| classic | 2022-01-05 10:15:22 | 2022-01-05 10:20:23 | member |
| electric | 2022-01-06 11:12:23 | 2022-01-06 11:15:13 | casual |
| docked | 2023-03-05 15:26:22 | 2023-03-05 15:36:36 | member |

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT
  member_casual,
  started_at,
  CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM started_at) AS int64) AS year
FROM
  `table`
WHERE
 year = 2022
```

but I get "unrecognized name:year and the year under the WHERE clause is underlined.
I need the year so I can see how the number of members change from 2022 to 2023, how do I go about do that?

Comment: What is the `CAST( ... AS int64)` supposed to be good for?

Comment: When I tried to use the Extract clause, it said something about not being able to get the year from the string, so I thought if I used the cast along with it, to make an integer, that it would be able to get the year.

Comment: If `EXTRACT(year FROM started_at)` results in an error that you cannot get a year from a string, this probably means that `started_at` is not appropriately stored as a timestamp, but as a string. Don't store dates/times as strings. Check your table definition. And invoking `CAST` on the result cannot help, because `EXTRACT` happens first.

Comment: Gotcha, I will look again at the datasets and verify if **started_at** is correctly stored as a timestamp. Thank you for the clarification. So IF the **started_at** was correctly stored as a timestamp, then all I would have needed in this case is the EXTRACT function?

Comment: Yes. As mentioned `CAST` cannot help you with any issue here, because you invoke it on the resulting year, so it happens after getting the year from the date.

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      member_casual,
      started_at,
      CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM started_at) AS int64) AS year
    FROM
      `table`
)
WHERE
 year = 2022
```

Also, you can use  `EXTRACT(year FROM started_at) AS year` without casting to int

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an alias defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause, because `SELECT` happens after `WHERE`.

You can use the same expression:

```
SELECT
  member_casual,
  started_at,
  CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM started_at) AS int64) AS year
FROM `table`
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM started_at) = 2022;
```

But it is a good habit to avoid manipulations on the columns in the `WHERE` clause, because this prevents the DBMS from using indexes on these columns where such exist. So better:

```
SELECT
  member_casual,
  started_at,
  CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM started_at) AS int64) AS year
FROM `table`
WHERE started_at >= DATE '2022-01-01'
  AND started_at <  DATE '2023-01-01';
```

If there exists an index on `started_at`, the query can greatly benefit from it.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the help! I thought that the WHERE clause processed after the SELECT clause, but now I realize why I was getting that warning.